# Java have join method, what node NodeJs have equivalent to it?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

As we know, Java have join method in multi-threading, I want to achieve the same in NodeJs. Is these any equivalent to join method of java in NodeJs?

**Below is my requirement:** 
I have 3 methods(m1(),m2(),m3()) which calculates huge data and returns a number. Then i have one Sum() method which adds all three numbers returned by these three(m1(),m2(),m3()) methods. As these three methods are taking approx. 10 min each to calculate the data, my sum() method have to wait for approx. 30 mins to start executing. So i want to execute these three(m1(),m2(),m3()) methods parallelly. But my condition here is, The Sum method should start execute only when all three methods complete their execution and add the data returned by three methods.

Comment: What exactly do you want to `join`? A worker thread? A promise?

Comment: You know that node js is basically single threaded? Are you asking about waiting for multiple processes to end?

Comment: Below is my requirement:
I have 3 methods(m1(),m2(),m3()) which calculates huge data and returns a number. Then i have one Sum() method which adds all three numbers returned by these three(m1(),m2(),m3()) methods. As these three methods are taking approx. 10 min each to calculate the data, my sum() method have to wait for approx. 30 mins to start executing. So i want to execute these three(m1(),m2(),m3()) methods parallelly. But my condition here is, The Sum method should start execute only when all three methods complete their execution and add the data returned by three methods.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does not have the concept of multi-threading, since JavaScript by default runs single-threaded. Hence you don't have something such as `join`. Instead, you need to get to know concepts such as the event loop, callbacks, promises & co.

(Yes, to be true, Node.js meanwhile has the concept of [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), which allow multi-threading, but this is still experimental.)

Answer (score 0):

All Node JS applications uses “Single Threaded Event Loop Model” architecture to handle multiple concurrent clients.

NodeJs operate asynchronously and uses the Event-loop mechanism to function.

And join method in JAVA allows one thread to wait until another thread completes its execution. So this can be achieved in Javascript using Promises or Async/Await.

Comment: Hi Shubham,
I am very new to NodeJs. So can you please give me some demo code for this scenario.?

Comment: Hi @RaJanKumar, sure look at this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zdk7ju?file=index.js